# Docker compose Amazon ECS

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

As I am quite familiar with docker compose and not so familiar with amazons cloudformation I found it extremely nice to be able to basically run your docker compose files via ecs integration and viola behind the scenes everything you need is created for you. So you get your load balancer (if not already created) and your ecs cluster with your services running and everything is connected and just works. When I started wanting to do a bit more advanced things I ran into a problem that I can't seem to find an answer to online.

I have 2 services in my docker compose, my spring boot web app and my postgres db. I wanted to implement ssl and redirect all traffic to https. After a lot of research and a lot of trial and error I finally got it to work by extending my compose file with x-aws-cloudformation and adding native cloudformation yaml. When doing all of this I was forced to choose an application load balancer over a network load balancer as it operates on layer 7 (http/https). However my problem is that now I have no way of reaching my postgres database and running queries against it via for example intellij. My spring boot app works find and can read/write to my database so that works fine. Before the whole ssl implementation I didn't specify a load balancer in my compose file and so it gave me a network load balancer every time I ran my compose file. Then I could connect to my database via intellij and run queries. I have tried adding an inbound rule on my security group that basically allows all inbound traffic to my database via 5432 but that didn't help. I may not be setting the correct host when applying my connection details in intellij but I have tried using the following:

1. dns name of load balancer
2. ip-adress of load balancer
3. public ip of my postgres db task (launch type: fargate)

I would just like to simply reach my database and run queries against it even though it is running inside aws ecs cluster behind an application load balancer. Is there a way of achieving what I am trying to do? Or do I have to have 2 separate load balancers (one application LB and one network LB)?

Here is my docker-compose file(I have omitted a few irrelevant env variables):

```
version: "3.9"

x-aws-loadbalancer: arn:my-application-load-balancer

services:
  my-web-app:
    build:
      context: .
    image: hub/my-web-app
    x-aws-pull_credentials: xxxxxxxx
    container_name: my-app-name
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - my-app-network
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 2048M
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/my-db?currentSchema=my-db_schema
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=dbpass
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=dbpass
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME=org.postgresql.Driver
      - SPRING_JPA_DATABASE_PLATFORM=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

  postgres:
    build:
      context: docker/database
    image: hub/my-db
    container_name: my-db
    networks:
      - my-app-network
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 2048M
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=dbpass
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=dbpass
      - POSTGRES_DB=my-db

networks:
  my-app-network:
    name: my-app-network

x-aws-cloudformation:
  Resources:
    MyWebAppTCP80TargetGroup:
      Properties:
        HealthCheckPath: /actuator/health
        Matcher:
          HttpCode: 200-499
    MyWebAppTCP80Listener:
      Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
      Properties:
        Protocol: HTTP
        Port: 80
        LoadBalancerArn: xxxxx
        DefaultActions:
          - Type: redirect
            RedirectConfig:
              Port: 443
              Host: "#{host}"
              Path: "/#{path}"
              Query: "#{query}"
              Protocol: HTTPS
              StatusCode: HTTP_301
    MyWebAppTCP443Listener:
      Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
      Properties:
        Protocol: HTTPS
        Port: 443
        LoadBalancerArn: xxxxxxxxx
        Certificates:
          - CertificateArn: "xxxxxxxxxx"
        DefaultActions:
          - Type: forward
            ForwardConfig:
              TargetGroups:
                - TargetGroupArn:
                    Ref: MyWebAppTCP80TargetGroup
    MyWebAppTCP80RedirectRule:
      Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
      Properties:
        ListenerArn:
          Ref: MyWebAppTCP80Listener
        Priority: 1
        Conditions:
          - Field: host-header
            HostHeaderConfig:
              Values:
                - "*.my-app.com"
                - "www.my-app.com"
                - "my-app.com"
        Actions:
          - Type: redirect
            RedirectConfig:
              Host: "#{host}"
              Path: "/#{path}"
              Query: "#{query}"
              Port: 443
              Protocol: HTTPS
              StatusCode: HTTP_301
```

Comment: You should really be using RDS instead of ECS for your database. As it is, any deployments are going to wipe all your data from your database because the data is stored on an ephemeral ECS volume.

Comment: I know RDS is preferred and I will probably look into making a switch later. But it is a lot easier to have everything in one docker compose file. If I was able to set up an RDS instance via docker compose then that would have been lovely because I wouldn't have to manually set it up or use terraform to set it up and connect to it via my ecs cluster. Data is not being wiped between deployments. I omitted  the lines where I mount a volume, which creates an EFS file system with retain policy so no data will be wiped -> [see doc](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/#volumes)

Comment: You are going beyond what is capable with the ECS docker-compose integration. It's really only intended for very standard setups. Once you get into anything more complicated you either need to add a bunch of CloudFormation code to that, or just switch to using something else entirely like Terraform. If you were using RDS it would be a simple checkbox to check to make the database server accessible from your computer.